# Connect negative terminal of a battery to Earth

Tags: electrostatics, electric-circuits, voltage, batteries, electrochemistry

I have a question about what happens
in following experiment: Assume we have
a battery with two Galvanic half cell,
eg a magnesium and a copper cell.
Since copper has higher electrode potential
that magnesium, the electrode with
magnesium oxidizes and therefore becomes
the negative terminal und the electrode
with copper reduces and becomes
positive terminal.

I want to find out what happens at the
moment when we connect the earth?
(the earth is here considered as
electrostatically neutral uncharged source
with constant potential, which can
absorb und donate a huge amount of
electrons without changing it's potential) See also this image:

[image]

Question: What happens at the moment we
connect the negative terminal
(magnesium) having excess of electrons with
earth und leave simultaneously the positive terminal
unconnected?

Clearly, since the positive terminal is
unconnected, there cannot be a steady
current because there is no closed circuit between positive and negative terminals.

But I'm primary interested in electrostatic effects and want to know
if there happens a electrostatic
discharge at the contact moment within a very very short moment sending the
excess electrons from negative terminal
to earth or does there really literally
'nothing' happen?

Some ideas: Why I conjecture that such elecrostatic discharge should happen: At the moment when we connect
the earth to the magnesium electrode seemingly the unconnected copper electrode isn't noticed by the system earth-magnesium electrode since we assumed that there is no connection to the copper electrode:

[image]

And since the earth is neatrally charged and the magnesium electrode contains a lot of electrons on it, it seems reasonable that all this electrons 'want' to run into the neutral earth at the moment we connect the earth to the magnesium electrode. Does it sound reasonable.

That seems to be quite similar to the question what happens immediately after we connect the positive to negative terminals of two Galvanic half cells but remove the salt bridge:

[image]

Again, clearly without salt bridge there can no consistent current happen because the salt bridge closes the circuit as ion conductor.

But nevertheless, at the moment we connect the two terminals/electrods whith a wire, shouldn't the excessed electrons at magnesium electrode not nevertheless flow to copper electode and then stay there to compensate the charge/potential difference? And only then because due to lack of salt bridge everything stops?

Are my reasonings correct or if not what is my error? (I asked the same question [in physicsstack](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/661200/connect-negative-terminal-of-a-battery-to-earth/661221?noredirect=1#comment1483510_661221)

Comment: Please cite the source of your first diagram.

Comment: https://www.chemguide.co.uk/physical/redoxeqia/introduction.html#top

Comment: ...and thanks to insightful discussions below I 
came to conclusion that the linked introduction to
redox equilibria is very misleading, since the pictures
of electrode bars and electrons there could lead to wrong thoughts
that electrons in electrode bar are distributed there like in a
statically charged metal bar (what essentially caused
my confusion)

Comment: I think you got it. But I’m not sure any of the other answers completely considered that upon connecting the magnesium electrode to ground the capacitance between the positive electrolyte and earth could result in a transient current. I would have offered an answer along those lines but I’m not conversant enough in battery chemistry

Comment: For sake of completeness I found here (
https://www.semanticscholar.org/paper/How-batteries-discharge%3A-A-simple-model-Saslow/a0c56ec2a5578f180dea8b29df8e292177409273)

after long search a paper where the voltage is explained finally in a satisfactory way 
instead of this weird oversimplified and also wrong
school book explanantion that allegedly the potential difference between the two terminals of a
battery "arise due to excess of electrons in anode
and lack of electrons in cathode", which can be found in first 50 or 100 entries if you
google "potential difference in battery".

Comment: Following this deceptive "logic" if you connect a half-cell 
with equilibrium Me <-> Me+n + ne^- to the Earth, the Earth would have absorb the electrons on the
right, as in the case when you connect a statically negatively charged metal sphere to Earth!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The situation of the extra electrons in the magnesium bar is different of a bar with an excess of electrons due to friction for example. In this second case, any connection with the earth tends to neutralize the bar.

But the system magnesium bar + electrolyte must be taken as a whole. The excess of electrons in the bar are not free only because they are far from the positive ions in the solution. So, connecting it to the earth is like breaking the glass of an aquarium with coral reefs and fishes, connecting it to the ocean. The fishes have nothing to actract them out from its source of food.

The same happens if the bars are connected without also connecting the solutions. We can not think of the electrons in each bar forggeting its
interactions with the ions.

Only after bars and solutions are connected we have another system, composed by the bars and the electrolyte, and a system out of equilibrium while the chemical reaction is running.

Comment: So your argument is that if we consider a general half-cell this 
consists of two components, the metal bar, a lattice of Me-atoms and 
a electrolyte solution, in our example with magnesium the electrolyte 
solution is MgSO4 and depending on the chemical equilibrium Mg <-> Mg2+ + 2e 
some magnesium atoms give their electrons up "into the bar" and dissociate 
as positive Mg2+ ions into the solution. That's the background, now the 
punchline (if I correctly understood you):

Comment: You mean that the released 
electrons in the magnesium bar and not really "free" in the
sense that that if we connect to the magnesium bar 
to a conductor which is less neagative charged, then the
electrons will NOT be able without any obstacles to move there, beacause they 
are also attracted to the surface by the positive Mg2+ ions which bustle 
at the phase between the bar surface and the solution, that the point?
So due to the opposed charges these ions prevent the
negative electrons to "leave" the magnesium bar if we 
connect it to neutrally charged earth.

Comment: So in summary the punshline is that the presence of these Mg2+ at the 
surface-solution contact phase which with their positive charge fixing 
the electrons in the magnesium bar preventing them from flying away to 
eg neutrally charnged earth? Did I reproduce correct your point?

Comment: Yes, that is. The bar with excess of electrons and the solution with an excess of positive ions is a configuration energetically more favorable than both parts neutral. It is different from a metallic bar alone with excess of electrons.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have a firm grasp on the chemistry, but the reaction is limited by the voltage *difference* between the two electrodes. The action of the cell will tend to keep that difference constant. So, if there's a transient flow of electrons from the negative terminal to ground that raises the voltage of that terminal with respect to ground by some amount,* then I would expect an equivalent amount of positive charge (i.e., half as many "+2" ions) to flow across the salt bridge, and raise the voltage of the positive terminal by the same amount.

---

* That is, assuming that the initial voltage of the negative terminal W.R.T. ground was less than zero. Making the electrical connection to ground in that case "raises" the voltage to zero.

Comment: You wrote in your answer 
'if there's a transient 
flow of electrons...' .then as you 
said as a consequence there should flow 
an equivalent 
amount of positive charge flow across
the salt bridge to compansate the 
charge loss at negative potential.
So how I understand you here is that 
if such flow *hypothetically (!)* would
happen, then the consequences would be...

Comment: But my question is exactly if such transient flow of electrons from the negative terminal to ground really happens in nature (so if it detectable or only hypothetical).

Answer (score 1):

No current will occur since there is no potential difference between the battery clemma an the Earth.

On the other hand, lightnings are happening pricisely due to existing such a potential difference.

Comment: Yes I argree with you that of course 
there could no steady current happen, 
simply because there is nowhere 
a *closed* circuit, that's what I 
already remarked in the question.

Comment: In the second sentence you refer to a 
'potential difference'
between negative terminal and earth, right?
(maybe a stupid question but since there
is also a 
'potential difference' between 
the two terminals of the battery involved,
I wanted to assure that the 
'potential difference' you are talking in
your answer is that one between the
negative terminal and earth)

Comment: If I understand you correctly, then after connecting the negative terminal with the earth there should indeed happen for very short moment a electrostatic discharge by absorbation of electrons from negative terminal by earth. Followed by the movement of ions flowing across the salt bridge to compensate the lost charge in order to keep the potential difference between both battery terminals constant, right? And only then nothing more happens in this system?

Comment: No even electrostatic discharge may happen. For the Earth the battery is neutral as any other body consisting of equal number of positively and negatively charges.

Comment: I'm still confused. Of course the battery as *total system* is neutral, but 
we assumed that we connect the earth only to the negative terminal 
chunk inhabited with all theese electrons 
(=magnesium electrode); which are "given up" by the magnesium atoms swimming
now as possitively charged $2+$-ions. So seemingly as long as we keep
the positive terminal (=copper electrode) disconnected, the earth 'sees' only
this negatively charged magnesium chunk inhabited with all theese electrons.
What prevents then the electrons from beeing absorbed electrostatically
by the earth?

Answer (score 1):

The electrochemical reaction tries to maintain a constant potential difference between the magnesium and the copper with the copper being at a higher potential than the magnesium.
You can think of the electrochemical reaction a being like a pump which has the effect of producing a net movement of negative charges from one terminal (which becomes the positive terminal of the cell - copper) to the other terminal (which becomes the negative terminal of the cell - magnesium).
The excess charges on the two electrodes set up an electric field inside the cell in opposition to the migration of the charges and eventually the magnitude of that electric field is sufficient to stop the migration of charges between the two electrodes.  There is then a constant potential difference between the two terminals.

What you do not know is the potential of the earth relative to either of the two electrodes.

If the potential of the earth is the same as that of the magnesium then connecting the two together has no effect.

If the potential of the earth is higher than that of the magnesium electrode before a connection is made, then the potential of the copper must rise to maintain the constant potential difference between the copper and the magnesium.
There will therefore be a net migration of negative charges from the copper, through the cell, to the earth until the potential difference between copper and magnesium is the same as it was before the connection was made.

If the potential of the earth is lower than that of the magnesium electrode before a connection is made, then the potential of the copper must fall to maintain the constant potential difference between the copper and the magnesium.
There will therefore be a net migration of negative charges from the earth, through the cell, to the copper until the potential difference between copper and magnesium is the same as it was before the connection was made.

The statement *since the earth is neutrally charged* that was made is possibly the reason why the question was asked.  The important parameter is not the quantity of excess charge resident on the earth rather it is the potential difference between the earth and the copper/magnesium.

The removal of the salt bridge whilst the copper and magnesium are connected does indeed lead to a net migration of negative charges from the magnesium to the copper until the potential difference between the two is zero.

Comment: You wrote about the case if the potential of earth is higher than that
of the magnesium electrode. There you wrote that in this case 
as a consequence of the battery's effort to maintain 
 the constant potential difference between the copper and the magnesium
electrodes, there will be a net migration of negative charges 
from the copper throgh the cell to the earth.

Comment: How is it possible? I assume you are talking there about the first 
experiment from my opener where we connect the negative 
terminal to the earth and leave the positive terminal unconnected.
How can in this case concretely negative charges from the copper (!) migrate
through the cell? Since there is no connection to positive terminal
(=copper), seemingly the electrons from there have "no way" to migrate
to earth, or do I miss some important aspect?

Comment: If you have a potential difference across a piece of wire charges will flow until the potential difference is zero which will occur when the potential of the magnesium reaches the potential of the earth.  That cannot be the final state as there is now no potential difference between the magnesium and the copper so there must also be a redistribution of charge within the cell to achieve the final steady state potential difference across the cell.

Answer (score 0):

> I have a question about what happens in following experiment: Assume we have a battery with two Galvanic half cell, eg a magnesium and a copper cell. Since copper has higher electrode potential that magnesium, the electrode with magnesium oxidizes and therefore becomes the negative terminal und the electrode with copper reduces and becomes positive terminal.

You first need to put some electrolyte in water. The left vessel will need magnesium sulfate and the right vessel copper (II) sulfate. They dissolve in water and we'll have Zn++ and SO₄-- ions floating in the left and Cu++ and SO₄-- in the right vessel.

Magnesium is more reactive and will lose electrons more readily than copper so the magnesium bar will become the negative terminal (anode). Doubly ionised Mg++ ions from the bar will join the other Mg++ ions in the solution. They will pull Cl- ions from the salt bridge. The Na+ ions from the salt bridge will dissolve in the right vessel and the Cu++ ions will stick to the copper cathode bar, which attracts it using the electrons it took from the magnesium bar. Presently, everything is neutral.

None of that happens of course until you connect the cathode to the anode with a conductor.

> Question: What happens at the moment we connect the negative terminal (magnesium) having excess of electrons with earth und leave simultaneously the positive terminal unconnected?

If the copper terminal is unconnected, the magnesium bar does not have excess electrons. It has as many electrons as it has protons, it's electrically neutral. Connecting magnesium to the earth will have no effect. You might as well not connect it to anything. Also, there is neither positive nor negative terminal in a cell until you connect the terminals. A brand-new battery with a plus and a minus sign printed on it does not really have these terminals until you close that circuit; they become terminals in that instant. And because one metal is more eager to lose electrons than the other.

Nothing happens in the electrolyte either, the ions continue floating  unaware of the earth having been plugged in to the magnesium bar.

> That seems to be quite similar to the question what happens immediately after we connect the positive to negative terminals of two Galvanic half cells but remove the salt bridge

Without the salt bridge, some electrons will be exchanged between magnesium and copper but not many because the loss/gain of electrons will make magnesium slighly positive, preventing it from donating any more electrons and the copper will become slightly negative and therefore less eager to accept electrons. Nothing will happen. You needed that salt bridge to maintain the reaction but now it will stop before it really begins.

And the magnesium bar will not remain slighly positively charged just because it's easier for it to lose electrons. Copper can lose electrons for magnesium as well just somewhat less often.

So basically you're under the incorrect impresion that there are excess electrons in the magnesium bar. I think this is the source of all the confusion.

**Some additional remarks.**
NOTHING travels across the bridge. Neither Mg nor Cu can travel across the bridge. The bridge has the job of keeping the electrolytes from mixing. However, it's filled with Na+Ch- which can leave the bridge and enter the vessels.

Next thing, metals have free electrons that are in constant motion and they are free to travel anywhere throughout the volume of the conductor. If you bring two pieces of metal in physical contact, their free electrons will now be able to cross from one to another, in both ways so there will be no net flow.

The Earth doesn't have the same propensity because it doesn't have as many free electrons as a metal, plus it's conductivity may be partially due to moisture. Earth is not objectively speaking as good a conductor as a metal, however it does a good job at conducting electricy dues to it's 3-dimensional geometry, whereas wires for example are one dimensional.

So there is a difference between metals and earth. Take also under consideration, the vastly varying orders of magnidute involved in electricity. There are about $6\cdot 10^{15}$ electrons per second in one miliampere, but there may be microamperes, picoamperes, at some point we would stop caring that there is a current if it's too small to detect. One electron is already a current. And absent electron generates electric field that will pull it back so we again have a current but in the opposite direction. This happens all the time but we won't measure it with any devices because it's quick and net is zero.

You need that salt bridge. You need all the parts for anything to happen.

Comment: About the "Magnesium is more..." part:
Probably you want to say that because magnesium is more reactive than copper
and therefore tends stronger to lose it's electrons the
the magnesium bar becomes **negative** terminal?
(See the "definitions" part here:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galvanic_cell#Half_reactions_and_conventions)

Comment: Moreover when you say "They will pull Cl- ions from the salt bridge"
 probably you mean the SO₄-- ions from the right vessel which 
are attracted by Mg++ ions and can pass through the salt bridge.
What do you mean by "The Na+ ions from the salt bridge will 
dissolve in the right vessel"?

Comment: Also I not completely understand the following part. On one hand
you say that if the the copper terminal is unconnected, then
if we connect only the magnesium bar to earth then 
no electrons will flow to earth because the half cell/terminal
consisting of magnesium bar sitting in the electrolyte
is electrically neutral: The number of electrons in the bar 
is the same as the number of protons in water/electrolyte
solution, right?

Comment: On the other hand consider the second story where we connect the two 
terminals but remove the salt bridge. You say that here at the moment
of connection there will short, but not permanent 
flow of electrons between two terminals. Why in this case there will be
a electron flow, but in case of connecting the nagative terminal 
to earth there is no short flow (note, when I say "short flow" I only
mean only short electrostatic effect; of course in both cases
no permanent current is possible)?

Comment: Indeed applying the same logic as for earth-negative terminal case,
when we connect the two terminal and let the salt bridge 
be removed, then each of the two terminals has 
the same number of electrons in the bar 
as the number of protons in water/electrolyte
solution. So each terminal is due to this argumentation neutral and 
applying this "logic" as above there should be no electron flow
between the two terminals.

Comment: Nevertheless you say that in latter case
 some electrons will be exchanged between magnesium and copper. Why?
What is the crucial difference between these two experiments from viewpoint
that in one case there is no electon flow, in the other it shortly happens?

Comment: The magnesium bar is the anode (negative terminal). You're right about that one. I added a few other remarks to the answer.